# How Can I Use Canny To 32bit grayscale？

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 32bit grayScale Image and I want to detecte the edge, I want to use Canny and use opencv? but opencv canny function only support 8bit? want should I do?

I also want to use c++ to realize the canny function.but I do not konw how to do it.

Comment: Convert a 32 bit opencv mat to a 8 bit?

Comment: @cplusplusrat And lose the precision? Is it really the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the image's pixel value between 0 and 255 and the convert the image to CV_8U. Something like this:

```
img = img - min_val;
img = img*255.0/(max_val - min_val);
img.convertTo(img,CV_8U);
```

Now feed img to canny algorithm ( `min_val` and `max_val` are the minimum and maximum intensity of your image respectively.)